# Socket.IO throws error after app has been built

Tags: node.js, react-native, websocket, socket.io, polling

I am working on a project, which is using Socket.IO as a live communication between client (React Native app) and server (node js app). When in development, everything was working fine, but after I've built the React Native app and tried connecting to the server, I am getting the `xhr poll error`.

I've tried adding the `transports: ["websocket"]` option when creating the socket, as some comments in similar posts suggested, but that just changed the error to the `websocket error`. Any ideas what's the problem here?